# bullet movement SDL/c++

Tags: c++, sdl, game-physics

I want a bullet to move when I click Space. First the bullet image is blitted when space is pressed, at the same time a timer starts and when it reaches 5000 ms ticks the x-value of the image should change. This is my code:

```
SDL_Rect bulletRect;
bulletRect.x = dstX+31;  //dstX/Y is the source destination of another image where the bullet should be drawn
bulletRect.y = dstY+10.5;
SDL_Surface *bullet = IMG_Load(bullet.png");
```

```
if (drawBullet) //bool set to true in the space key event.
    {            
        SDL_BlitSurface(bullet, NULL, screen, &bulletRect);

        //timer
        my_timer.start(); //starts the timer

        if (SDL_GetTicks() == 5000) //if 5 sec 
        {
            bulletRect.x += 10;
        }
    }
```

The image is only blitted but nothing happens after 5 sec. What is wrong?

Comment: I really recommend looking into the [`Model|View|Controller`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `SDL_GetTicks() >= 5000`, instead of checking for `==5000`, otherwise you'll only enter the condition if you happen to hit 5000 by pure luck.

from [SDL's documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GetTicks), SDL_GetTicks function: Returns the number of milliseconds since SDL library initialization. This value wraps around if the program runs for more than 49.7 days

so if you're checking that it's been 5 seconds since it moved last (not sure what else you could be trying to do here) you want to store the current number of ticks and use that to compare against during the next loop (check that the difference between previous and current is > 5000)

Comment: you have if(drawBullet), which is called when the user presses the space bar, then you have a timer and a check for number of ticks. If you only drop into that condition after a space bar event, what is your timer doing? will SDL_getTicks ever be reset, or does it keep incrementing? in which case your if statement only ever does anything in the first 5 seconds of your program.

Comment: But I got this to work by just moving the SDL_Blitsurface(...) to after the if(SDL_GetTicks()..) statement

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional statement

```
if (SDL_GetTicks() == 5000) //if 5 sec 
{
    bulletRect.x += 10;
}
```

is inside the statement

```
if (drawBullet) //bool set to true in the space key event
```

which means you only check the timer once when the spacebar is pressed. Move this outside the if(drawBullet)